# incorporating bootstrap theme for Forem gem on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, forem

I'm trying to have forums on an application i'm writing. I've got the forum working through the installation found on http://www.sitepoint.com/forem-rails-forum-engine/

The error I'm getting is:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Forem::Forums#show
File to import not found or unreadable: forem-bootstrap
```

It highlights the code from `vendor/assets/stylesheets.forem.css.scss`

```
@import 'forem-bootstrap';
```

I've bundle installed the gem the installation site told me inside my Gemfile:

```
gem 'forem-bootstrap', github: "radar/forem-bootstrap"
```

If I get rid of the `@import` line from `stylesheets/forem.css.scss` it loads the forums just fine. Any ideas how to get the bootstrap gem to work with Forem?

Comment: This looks fishy `vendor/assets/stylesheets.forem.css.scss` maybe it should be `vendor/assets/stylesheets/forem.css.scss`

Comment: yep, my mistake thats supposed to be a path